# Query Oracle for new data based on properties of visible markers?

Tags: r, leaflet, oracle-spatial, shiny

I'm very new to R/Shiny/Leaflet.

I have a barebones working example where I can display points on map based on their lat/long in a table I pull from Oracle:

```
siteData <- conn %>% tbl(in_schema("SCHEMANAME", "TABLENAME")) %>% as.data.frame();

function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -93.85, lat = 37.45, zoom = 4)
  })
...
  observe({
    colorBy <- input$color
    sizeBy <- input$size
    
    
    leafletProxy("map", data = siteData) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(~LONGITUDE, ~LATITUDE,
                       popup=
                         ~paste("ID: ", as.character(ID), "<br>",
                                "Latitude: ", as.character(LATITUDE) , "<br/>" ,
                                "Longitude: ", as.character(LONGITUDE) , "<BR/>" 
                                ),
                       clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions()) 
  })
```

I have an additional table with polygons that I only want to show at certain zoom levels.  Basically, once close-enough in, I want to take the IDs of the points currently in view, go to the db and pull the polygons whose IDs match.

I see the flow like this:
What is the current zoom level?
If the zoome level is appropriate, what are the visible points?
What are the IDs of the visible points?
`SELECT * FROM details WHERE ID in (<set of ID's of visible points>)` and then render the returned polygons.

Many of the examples I see seem to assume that you have all the data you need in a single pull, and I don't want to draw that many polygons at once.  I'd rather pay the toll for latency than browser memory.

====EDITED TO ADD====

The column that holds the polygon in the detail table is coded as:

```
    SDO_GEOMETRY(    
        2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
        NULL,
        NULL,
        SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), -- EXTERIOR POLYGON
        SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY( 
                LONGITUDE , LATITUDE ,
                LONGITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*COS(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2)), LATITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*SIN(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2))  ,
                LONGITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*COS(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + B.BEAMWIDTH/4 )),LATITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*SIN(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + B.BEAMWIDTH/4))  ,
                LONGITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*COS(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 2*B.BEAMWIDTH/4)),LATITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*SIN(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 2*B.BEAMWIDTH/4))  ,
                LONGITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*COS(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 3*B.BEAMWIDTH/4)),LATITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*SIN(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 3*B.BEAMWIDTH/4))  ,
                LONGITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*COS(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 4*B.BEAMWIDTH/4)),LATITUDE + C.ROW_NUMBER*0.0001*SIN(0.017456329*(A.AZIMUTH - B.BEAMWIDTH/2 + 4*B.BEAMWIDTH/4))  ,
                LONGITUDE , LATITUDE
            )
    ) AS SECTORPOLYGON
```

Comment: You are asking this with the oracle-spatial tag, so I assume that those polygons are stored as rows in a table with the polygon shape encoded using the `SDO_GEOMETRY` type. Is this correct ? If so you need a spatial query that returns those polygons that interact with those points ?

Comment: Or is this purely based on IDs, i.e. each point has an attribute called something like POLYGON_ID that represents the id of the polygon that contains that point ?

Comment: Then again any respectable map generation library has options to only show the content of a layer at a certain scale range.

Comment: I agree that the controlling the layer content by zoom level is not really the issue.  But, I don't want to overload the browser with 250k polygons when they're not useful at a 30k foot view.  Hence the comment to prefer network time over browser time.  

I have some freedom in whether I save the column as an SDO_GEOMETRY object or a string representing a GeoJSON object.  It appears with some testing that the GeoJSON object plays friendlier with R/Leaflet.

Comment: There are two options here: one is to setup your mapping client so that it only shows that layer from a certain zoom level. For example, if the polygons you deal with are building outlines, then only start showing them when zoomed close enough that they make sense viewing.

Comment: The other option used by mapping tools is to use a sampling mechanism, i.e. only select a random sample of features so that a map only shows a few thousands of them. Then as you zoom in, more and more are shown.